# Sharepoint List- Custom Views

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

Situation: I am creating sharepoint list in office 365 that needs custom viewing options for users.

**Sharepoint list details**: The sharepoint list will be used by a group of users (say group A with a,bc....z as members) to create entries. The requirement is that members a,b,c...z should not be able to see entries from others members and see their respective entries only. There needs to be another group of users (say group B), that should be able to see all the entries from group A.

Can this requirement be satisfied in sharepoint office 365? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achiev this by Item-level Permissions in list settings-> advanced settings. Choose Read items that were created by the user for Read access and Create items and edit items that were created by the user for Create and Edit access.

Then you need to give group A edit permission, group B approve permissions
[image]